# Make an Android app out of website

Tags: android

I have a small wordpress website and I wanted to try to make an Android app out of it. But, I have no idea from where to begin. I found out about App Inventor which makes it real easy to create apps. But, what I still haven't figured out is how to extract data from my website and put it into the app through the App Inventor. 
Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try parsing the HTML content of you website and get the data at runtime. 
Simply use HTTP GET methods to hit your website url and then retrieve the contents and show it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact look of your website, you can go ahead with [appsgeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/). It automatically creates your app.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But actually I dont want to have the exact look of my website. I have another layout in mind for the app. But now what I need is to find a way to retrieve information from my website...